# ProcessStartInfo start "cmd.exe" to run "nvm" commands to install node versions pop up a program association error

Tags: c#, automation, .net-core, devops, nvm

I am trying to automate the machine setup using net core 2.0 with a console application, and I need to run some nvm commands to configure node versions.

I am trying to run a .bat file with the nvm commands that I need, but I am getting the following error:

This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel.

If I execute the .bat file directly from cmd it works ok, but when my console app run it I get this error.

The 'file.bat' commands are:

```
nvm version
nvm install 6.11.4
nvm use 6.11.4
nvm list
npm --version
```

My csharp function to run the command:

```
public static int ExecuteCommand()
{
    int exitCode;
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
    Process process;

    processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", $"/C file.bat")
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    };

    process = Process.Start(processInfo);

    process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray;
        Console.WriteLine("cmd >" + e.Data);
        Console.ResetColor();
    };
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) =>
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        Console.ResetColor();
    };
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

    process.WaitForExit();

    exitCode = process.ExitCode;

    Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: " + exitCode.ToString(), "ExecuteCommand");
    process.Close();

    return exitCode;
}
```

My expectation is to have this working, because after that I will need to run several other commands, like npm install, gulp install, etc.

Any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: Please include the _actual_ contents of your batch file. Also, do you use the same user to run the batch file separately and run the C# code?

Comment: Thanks for replying! The file.bat content It was already on the question, but I changed to make more clear. I use the same user (my) to run both. If I run this bat directly on "cmd" it works pretty fine, but if it is executed by C# as above, it throws that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based purely on testing, if you change this section:

```
processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", $"/C file.bat")
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
};
```

to not use the constructor arguments and instead manually set parameters like:

```
processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = $"/C file.bat",
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true
};
```

should do the trick. Not sure on why, since from github code on ProcessStartInfo the constructor merely receives arguments and stores them on respective properties (FileName and Arguments).

Comment: it was really that, thank you! I don't know why too, but now it is working pretty fine :D